# How to make curved border of a div block?

Tags: css, html, markup

There is a plcture of some 
[landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ektH7.png). As we can see a there is a curved border of header's div. How to curve it up like that in a browser?

Comment: Without a link to the page, it's hard to say exactly. This could easily be done with just a background image to give the simulation. It could also be accomplished with CSS shapes, but that would be more complex.

In the future, please post the code you've tried in order to show a modicum of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect can be achieved using the "border-radius" property in CSS.

Edit -

Further to @Patrick's comment, without a link to the actual page where we can inspect the HTML directly, it's difficult to tell how this effect has been achieved. It could be as simple as a background image, or a more complicated solution using shapes like Patrick suggested.

Comment: I believe they were referring to the "wave" effect.

Comment: You know I think you're right! Edit incoming :)